# Wordpress - Visual composer responsive image swap disable margins on mobile-tab devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive, visual-composer

I create two rows in visual composer both with 3/3 alignment. On the first one i place three swap images, dimensions 380x190px. On the second one I add two swap images with the same dimensions and I use css margin-left:150px for the 1st and  margin-right:150px for the second to bring them more to the center.  You can see the result I get to the PC browser on attached image1-pc.png Visually is exactly what i want.

BUT
My problem is that on mobile and tablet devices the responsive result is spoiled due to the margins. So the last 2 of five swap images does not appear exactly under the others in order. You can see the result on attached image2-mobile.pngenter image description here.

-How can I solve this? Is any way via visual composer to deactivated those two margins for other devices?
-Or should I do it manually by making two rows both 1/1, add inside them html block to create it on my own by using custom css code with responsive options?

Thanks in advance for your time.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a page builder and not CSS.

Comment: The last question of my post includes css.